# burninate the [index] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-burnination

The [index](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/index) tag has just 85 questions, no usage guidance.

> 1. It doesn't tell much about the question.
> 2. Does not add much meaningful information to the question

What can we describe with that tag? the index file? It can also be a home file if anyone means the default file in the web development. There's no use for keeping it burninate it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No one watches this tag, it has few questions, and it has no obvious use. It should indeed be burninated.

Comment: should I edit some questions with the tags to remove them?

Comment: Go right ahead! It's not likely anybody can stand to do them all at once.